# Xcode freezes (and crashes) when clicking on a JSON file in the Project Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a very basic project set up with 3 `json` files for Lottie animations, but when I click on one of them in my Project Navigator, Xcode will freeze and eventually become unresponsive.

The `json` file is not big either (160 KB). What's the cause behind this freezing. Is it a bug in Xcode right now or are you not meant to see your `json` files other than in "quick view" mode?

I'm running Xcode 12.5.

Comment: It's hard to see what this has to do with programming or what you want from us. If Xcode is freezing / crashing, that's a bug, and you need to report it to Apple.

Comment: Well I posed this question because Xcode freezes and becomes unresponsive and I couldn't figure out the reason why. I thought posting the question here would benefit people who might have similar problems with their Xcode. I'm sorry you didn't like my question.

Comment: Are you working on Mac machine with M1 chip?

Comment: I'm using 2.2 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7 processor

Comment: I came here because of big Lottie files too... I don't think those are meant to be edited manually and as such they are minified to save space which Xcode has a hard time rendering - see my answer below.

Comment: 160 KB is actually a lot for source code editor. The problem is usually caused by code highlighting and indexing. I am not saying that the app should crash, but I have seen other professional editors do the same, e.g. JetBrains.

Comment: The same problem is even happening on my M1 iMac, it takes normally 20 to 50 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen with "minified" JSON (i.e. on a single line, as opposed to "pretty printed" with line returns and tabs/spaces): the longer the JSON, the longer the single line and some editors might have a hard time rendering it.

You could "pretty print" your JSON (outside of Xcode) to make it more digestible to the editor but be aware that this might result in significantly bigger (10x) JSON files.

Comment: A little question: so if you "pretty print" your JSON file using a 3rd party tool, does the Xcode show the content of the JSON file without freezing up?

Comment: Yes it should help but be aware that it will make your Lottie animation files bigger.
The question is: do you really need to see the content of your Lottie JSON files?
What I would rather recommend is to put them in a subfolder that you never touch to avoid opening them by mistake. (I know it's a pain when it happens...)

Comment: that's what I've been doing so far. I've put all my animation files in a folder so I don't click on them by mistake. I guess this will get fixed in later Xcode updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. i tried this:
My json file consisting of 612 different objects blocks Xcode. So I realized that the problem was that the objects were greater than 599. If I delete 13 objects, everything works fine.

Comment: So are you saying there’s a limit on the number of objects? Or does it pertain to the size of the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  I was trying to generate an output json file from C code using jansson.h.  In particular, I used the export command

json_dumpf(block, fpout, JSON_INDENT(0));

In this case, my data structure was in "block" and the output file stream in "fpout".  Xcode froze while trying to load the file.  Changing the zero to a one

json_dumpf(block, fpout, JSON_INDENT(1));

fixed the problem. My file size increased from 3.9 MB to 4 MB.

The documentation for jansson suggests the valid range for the argument to JSON_INDENT is 0 to 31 inclusive.  I guess that's not entirely true if one wants to use Xcode to view the result.